# Blue arrow pointer in Google Maps won't update whichever way I'm facing?

Tags: 4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, google-maps

On the Google Maps app, I see a blue arrow pointer. I've seen this on a previous version of maps back in Gingerbread. I think at some point in time, they removed this feature and made it look simply like a circle. But now I see that it's back. However, it seems to be stuck on the same direction regardless if I rotate my phone in whichever way.

Android reports on the notification bar that the "Location set by GPS" already so that rules out the possibility that it's still waiting for GPS data. The weird thing is it will sometimes change direction but on random occasions only. Is there a way to force it to re-calibrate or something? I find it really useful back then for navigating places where I'm not familiar with and would like to use it again now.

I'm now on Ice Cream Sandwich. Same phone.

EDIT:
I have downloaded 3rd party compass apps from the Play Store and they work without problems. The phone is ST17i.

Comment: Can we know the model of your phone? The blue arrow points your direction on the map using the magnetic compass and maybe your phone does not have one even though it has GPS.

Comment: I have downloaded 3rd party compass apps and those work. Plus, it worked fine back then on Gingerbread. I've updated my post above.

Comment: The hardware that is in use for your need is the digital compass rather than the GPS. Can you try compass related apps (like [GPS Status & Toolbox](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.eclipsim.gpsstatus2&feature=search_result#?t=W251bGwsMSwxLDEsImNvbS5lY2xpcHNpbS5ncHNzdGF0dXMyIl0.) which has a compass like view) with which you can make sure the hardware is working and is accessible by apps.

Comment: @Narayanan, tried both [GPS Status & Toolbar](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.eclipsim.gpsstatus2) and [Compass](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.apksoftware.compass). Both work and both point at the same north direction so I think that nulls the possibility of it being a hardware problem.

Comment: @Propeller What does GPS Status & Toolbox say under mag. field?

Answer (score -1):

had same problems b4 i tried calibrating the magnetic compass by the x ,y ,z axis here 8s the simple steps keep in mind all the rotations are clockwise directions first put your phone in a flat surface for me i placed it in a table and rotate it 3 full rotations clockwise then pick up your phone and face it on your left with the but part nearest to you and rotate it 3 full rotations clockwise and finally face your phone towards you like ussing it normaly and rotate it 3 full rotations clockwise and thats it ,for me it solved my prorblem reg the pointer in my map do this while your map is active ,hope this will help someone .

Comment: Please improve the quality of this question by using proper English, including capitalization and punctuation. As of current, it's hard to understand your answer.