# Google Maps blue arrow does not appear on the blue location dot (to show direction)

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-navigation, maps, compass

My Google Maps app shows a blue dot to indicate my current location, but (unlike on all of my friends' Google Maps), the blue dot does *not* show a compass-based arrow to indicate which direction I'm facing.

**How can I fix mine so that I can know which direction I'm facing?**

I've seen online that other people have had [similar problems](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/maps/pdfl46Fk61M) on iOS.

By the way, I've tried clearing cache, force-stopping the app, changing my language and fonts, calibrating my compass, and I've read [these tips](http://forums.macrumors.com/threads/google-maps-not-pointing-to-direction-of-travel.1523295/) too.

I want the direction-indicating arrow so that I know which way I'm facing even without entering a destination and switching into Navigation mode.

Also, double-tapping the "blue target" symbol in the bottom right (as [suggested here](http://forums.androidcentral.com/htc-one-m8/478664-what-s-arrowhead-google-maps-location-symbol.html)) does not change that symbol into a compass (or do anything different from single-tapping, which centers the map on my current location).

I'm using Android 6.0.1 on a Motorola Moto G4 Plus.

P.S. [This question](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/41212/blue-arrow-pointer-in-google-maps-wont-update-whichever-way-im-facing) is not relevant because that person *can* see the blue arrow, and my blue dot has no arrow at all.

Comment: Do you have high-accuracy location enabled?

Comment: 1000 views of this question with 0 upvotes! It must be a record. ☺

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I thought the Moto G4 Plus had no compass. I own one I like it but I thought it had no NFC or compass in the hardware. Maybe that is causing some of your issues?

Comment: Holy smokes. I never even considered that a smartphone these days might not have a magnetic sensor / compass. I assumed all phones did. Thanks for correcting my assumption!